# Split x axis for every value in graph, in Power BI

Tags: graph, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have the following graph in Power BI:

[image: my graph screenshot]

and I'm trying to recreate the below graph from Excel (note the X axis with the months February and January, **with** the `Operation Text`:

[image: excel graph screenshot]

As you can see, my attempt only displays the `Operation Text` rather than the month **and** `Operation Text`).

Here is what my current axis looks like:

[image: axis screenshot]

Changing the axis to have `Actual Start Date` on top, rather than the `Operation Text`:

[image: axis with start date on top]

Makes my graph look like this:

[image: graph after axis change]

Is it possible to achieve the same outcome as in Excel, with the values in my graph showing the two months side by side, for each operation text? If so, how can I do this?

I've tried looking into the X axis 'format' settings and wasn't able to see anything obvious to help achieve this. In addition, unfortunately the graph I'm looking to recreate is only a screenshot so I am unable to see how it achieves that outcome.

**EDIT:**

As suggested, I attempted to place `Operation Text` into the `Legend` field in my `Visualisations` section but I am unable to, due to the fact that I have two `Value` fields (the two columns `Actual Hours` and `Estimated Hours`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@CR7SMS is correct. You just need to expand down to the next level using that split arrow in the upper right of the visual so that this:

[image: Top Level]

Becomes this:

[image: Second Level]

Note that to get the axis to look like this, you'll need to sort on month rather than one of the measures.

[image: Sort]

You'll also want to turn off 'Concatenate labels' toggle in the 'Format > X axis' section of the visual settings.

[image: Format X axis]

Comment: Thanks! Accepting this because of the useful screenshots. I had to make sure my graph was also set to `Sort Descending`

Answer (score 1):

You would have to drill down one level, using the arrows seen at the top right of your first screenshot. For your specific purposes, the split arrow should do the trick. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried moving your date or operation text column in legend section ?..not 100% but something close to your requirement you can achieve

[image]

Comment: I'm unable to drag anything into the `Legend` section for some reason. When I attempt to drag a column into the field, the field changes to have bold dotted lines but the column cannot be placed inside. Edit: `This is a by design behavior. In Stacked Column Chart, when you add multiple fields into value section, it is not allowed to add legend. If you add field to legend, then, we can only add one field into value section.` - I guess this is not what I am looking for (source: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Legend-not-working-in-stacked-column-chart/td-p/502383)

Comment: I just attempted this with one value in my value field (just `Actual Hours`) and it sort of resembles what I'm looking for but I still need to have both `Actual Hours` and `Estimated Hours` columns visible at all times. Having them both in the graph prevents me from adding anything in the `Legends` field. Any ideas? I'm not sure what I'm looking for is even possible

Comment: Have you tried using clustered chart instead of stacked one..i am trying to find exact graph solution with some dummy data once I get i will update

Comment: Sorry, it's already a `Clustered Column Chart` (see OP screenshots)